# After remove # from url page refresh get error 404 in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, angularjs-routing

My Index file

```
 <base href="/"/>
```

In my controller added $Locatonprovider and redirect like this

```
 $location.path('/ui-login');

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

.htaccess file

```
      RewriteEngine On

      # if an existing  asset or directory is requested go to it  as          it is 
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
      RewriteRule ^ - [L]

      # if the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
      RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

my URL

http://localhost/index.html

**note: it's work but the problem was when I refresh the page get error 404 file not found**

Output:

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that your HTTP server has htaccess support turned on? Why are you even using htaccess? The [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) says you should avoid them almost at the very top of the page.

Comment: This file or directory exists. You probably have here directory named `ui-login`.

Comment: @Quentin I was trying to remove a .htaccess file and many sites and blogs suggested to add .htaccess file so but it's same error and thx for the response

Comment: @jiwopene — Why is the server responding with 404 Not Found if it exists?

Comment: @Rushidave — Client-side JavaScript can't help if the page won't load in the first place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180353/discussion-between-rushi-dave-and-quentin).

Comment: @Rushidave — Why? There's nothing more to say.

Comment: @Quentin ok thx